# How do you detect a "word" on a line that contains both letters and numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex, validation, sha

I need a regex that detects a "word" on a line that contains both letters and numbers and is a certain length, e.g. `812d555c726d10c77b05cd164705665a`. The goal is to detect lines that contain sha1 digests.

If a regex-only is too hard, a Ruby solution is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
valid_sha1 = !((str =~ /\b[a-f0-9]{32,}\b/i).nil?)
```

Comment: :-) :-)  We were both typing in our answers at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible to require that the word consist of BOTH letters and numbers? (Not just either.)

Comment: I guess this is good enough and will work 99.99 percent of the time.

Comment: @dan You don't want to require require BOTH letters and numbers.  Granted that that will be true most of the time, but I think it is theoretically possible for a hash to have only numeric or only alpha digits.

Comment: You probably should use `\b` anchors instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: Check for `nil` instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
s =~ /^[a-f0-9]{32,32}$/i
```

Comment: `{32,32}` can be written as `{32}`. And, since Jacob wants to *find* words in a longer line instead of requiring that the entire line *consists of* a 32-character hex number, use `\b` anchors instead of `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Both the other answers require the line begin with the SHA1.  If the sha1 can be anywhere in the line, remove the `^`

```
/[a-f0-9]{32}/i
```

You also don't need the second 32 in the curly braces, as if you only specify one number, it must match exactly that many.

Comment: the other answers have been modified since I posted this to reflect the contents of my post regarding the leading ^ and the unnecessary ,32

Comment: Be careful, there.  If you don't put the ^ at the beginning and the $ at the end (which I forgot in my answer, but have now edited), your pattern will match words that are longer than 32 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to require that the word consist of BOTH letters and numbers (as you ask above), then you can use positive lookahead:

```
sha_array = line.scan(/(?=.{0,31}\d)(?=.{0,31}[a-f])\b[\da-f]{32}\b/i)
```

The `(?=` checks a condition in advance, without consuming anything.